# Show that the solutions of the ODE form and n-dimensional vector space, choose a basis and write an expression for the most general solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

The ODE

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x) = f(x)$$

As far as I can get from my basic DE knowledge, the answer is probably some linear combo of $e^{x}$ just because it's derivatives are equal to itself. Not sure how to prove what they're asking tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the solution method given [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/HOHomogeneousDE.aspx). In short, you assume that the solutions to the equation are in the form of $f(x)=ce^{rx}$, so then you can write your equation as
$$cr^ne^{rt}-ce^{rt}=0$$
From there, you can factor out $ce^{rt}$ to get
$$ce^{rt}(r^n-1)=0$$
By the Zero Product Property and the fact that $ce^{rt}$ will never equal $0$ unless $c=0$, you can solve the equation
$$r^n=1$$
for $r$, to get $r=\sqrt[n]1$, which looks simple, but you need every solution. Use [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Roots_of_complex_numbers) to find all values of $r$. In this case, you're looking for the [Roots of Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity). Once you get them, use [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) to convert them into trig functions if necessary. Once you have all possible solutions, add them together.

I'll give you the example where $n=4$. In this case, we have to solve $r^4=1$. This has four solutions: $\{1,i,-1,-i\}$. Plugging those values back in for $r$, we have
$$f(x)=c_1e^x+c_2e^{ix}+c_3e^{-x}+c_4e^{-ix}$$
We could use Euler's Formula to convert the imaginary powers into trig functions, but I think that you can take it from here.

**Bonus:** The case where $n=2$ comes up in a lot of physics equations where force is dependent on position, like Hooke's Law,
$$F=-kx=m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$$